# Angular Search better approach

Tags: angular, html, angular-components

Lets assume that , I have a component hierarchy like

```
<app-component> 
<header></header>
<sidebar>
    <form-component>
</sidebar>
<sidebar />
    <breadcrum>
    <search-result />
</app-component>
```

This layout is contains a "Left side bar" which contains a form to search "students" based on input field like Name, age, sex.

The right side which contains a search-result component, needs to show this updated result set.

I am not able to understand , How can the result data can be passed to "search-result" in this case ?

Need inputs for 
 1. is the application component are properly placed ? 
 2. how to pass result "students" data between these components in order to show result ?

PS: I know @Input() & @Output but bit confused how can I use to provide result data to "Search result " component ?

Comment: You should use a service to communicate this data between the components

Comment: Put a common parent component above the sidebar and search-result components.

Comment: You commented on how you know the output decorator. You can use this decorator to set up an event emitter. You can let this event emitter emit the search result to the parent component (app-component in this case). Then you can use the input decorator to give the variable from the app-component to the search-result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this using messaging like architecture. Whenever a change occurs in sidebar (Could be keypress/search button click), let the other component know of this change. This can be implemented as shown below:

Have a service as shown below:

## DataService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{
private subject = new Subject<any>();
sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.subject.next({ obj: message });
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
}

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
}
```

## sidebar.component.ts:

```
  this.dataservice.sendMessage(send the object that you would require in the other 
  component)
```

## searchresult.component.ts

```
messagesubscription: Subscription;
constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {
  this.messagesubscription = this.dataservice.getMessage().subscribe((message) 
  => {
     if (message.obj) {
        // access the object here
     }
   });
}
```